Deleting inetorgperson fails with: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
I have set up an OpenLDAP server on Alma 8 with the nis schema and now realise that I need to replace the nis schema by rfc2307bis.  The installed schemas are as follows:
[root@foobox schema]# ldapsearch -LLL -Y external -H ldapi:/// -b cn=schema,cn=config -s one dnSASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth                                                                                                                        
SASL SSF: 0                                    
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={1}cosine,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config

In order to avoid any problems with the ordering of the schemas, my idea was to delete inetorgperson and nis and then add rfc2307 and inetorgperson.
However deletion of inetorgperson is failing with:
[root@foobox schema]# ldapdelete -v -Y external -H ldapi:/// cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
ldap_initialize( ldapi:///??base )
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
deleting entry "cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_delete: Server is unwilling to perform (53)

I have removed all the entries which used inetorgperson, so what could be causing the error?

Older OpenLDAP versions (2.4 and earlier) did not support deleting whole schema entries, or in fact any entries underneath cn=config – the backend literally didn't implement the delete operation.
You could, however, remove the unwanted attributes from the schema entry (or even empty it out completely) – the server doesn't stop you from undefining and then redefining attributes or objectClasses [even if they're in use!], and there is no distinction as to which entry defines what; it is all concatenated into a single schema anyway.
cn=config always uses a flat-file backend, so if you don't mind taking down the server for a minute, it is also possible to literally rm the respective LDIF file from /etc/openldap/slapd.d.

I'm using 2.6.6. Would that make a difference?

Looking a the information contained here, I think deleting a schema this way is just not possible.
